# Find eigenvalues without determinants

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2 $ be the linear transformation $T(a,b) = (2a+b, a+2b)$. Find the eigenvalues

I am trying to solve it without using determinants but I am stuck.

$2a+b = \lambda a$

$a+2b = \lambda b$

$(2-\lambda)a+b =0$

$a+(2-\lambda)b=0$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: That system of two equations must have a non-zero solution, hence...

Comment: From the equation $(2 - \lambda)a + b = 0$, you get $b = -(2 - \lambda)a$, which you can substitute into your final equation, to get an equation purely in terms of $a$ and $\lambda$. Note that, if $\lambda$ is a number such that $a$ must be $0$, then $b = -(2 - \lambda)a$ implies $b = 0$ too, which would mean that the system only has $(a, b) = (0, 0)$ as a solution (which is bad; $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue). So, assume $a$ and $b$ are non-zero (so you can divide by $a$ and $b$). Keeping all that in mind, what values can $\lambda$ take?

Comment: also, the eigenvalues of a square matrix of all $1's$  are fairly easy to work out. You have that matrix added to the identity.

Comment: Add the equations you will get $3(a+b)=\lambda (a+b).$ Then subtract them to get $a-b=\lambda(a-b).$ You can read off possible eigenvalues and eigenvectors as well.